# Set storage-driver in Docker Compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to run the DinD docker image with overlay2 drivers, so I'd normally execute (as explained in [dind Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/)):

```
docker run --privileged -d --name inner-docker docker:dind --storage-driver=overlay2
```

Is there a way to set *storage-driver* option in docker-compose.yml?

e.g.

```
app-docker:
  container_name: inner-docker
  image: docker:dind
  privileged: true
  storage_driver: overlay2
```

I could not find any trace in [compose file docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) (*overlay* is only referred as a network driver here).

I tried with *storage_driver*, *storage-driver* and similar with no luck.

There is an omonimous option discussed [here](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/6564), but it seems a totally different scope to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run below

```bash
docker run --privileged -d --name inner-docker docker:dind --storage-driver=overlay2
```

You are passing `docker:dind` arguments `--storage-driver=overlay2` and not passing an option to `docker run`. So use below

```yaml
app-docker:
  container_name: inner-docker
  image: docker:dind
  privileged: true
  command: --storage-driver=overlay2
```

Comment: You're right. Now I understand the `$@` in dind _dockerd-entrypoint.sh_ and other Dockerfiles.